# Most Efficient Way to Combine String Columns and Skip Particular Fields

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation

I will try to simplify my df:

```
Animal1  Animal2  Animal3
dog      cat      mouse
dog      0        mouse
0        cat      0
```

with just 3 records.

I wish to combine all 3 animals into a single field where it would look like the following column:

```
Animals
dog + cat + mouse
dog + mouse
cat
```

I think paste, or some kind of variation of it would be best but I cannot find my exact solution - I am sure it is easy. Maybe substituting the 0s with NAs would be a good first step?

Please note that it needs to be done for about 10 million rows.

Comment: I think I am going with the nested sub solution, but it is not perfect. Please see the following change to my df:
df2 <- data.frame(Animal1 = c("0", "dog", "dog", "0", "0"), 
Animal2 = c("0", "cat", "0", "cat","0"), 
Animal3 = c("mouse", "mouse", "mouse", "0","0")) It is not as clean for the Animals column as I would hope. Any other suggestions in how to improve this code? Note that I did not go with the Collapse function because I do not think R liked some of my empty columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested `sub` function to get the desired result:

```
df <- data.frame(Animal1 = c("dog", "dog", "0"), 
                 Animal2 = c("cat", "0", "cat"), 
                 Animal3 = c("mouse", "mouse", "0"))

df$Animals <- sub("\\+ 0", "", sub("0 \\+", "", paste(df$Animal1, df$Animal2, df$Animal3, sep = " + ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end define a `Collapse` function which takes a character vector, removes the "0" elements and collapses the rest into a string separated with plus signs.  Use `apply` to apply that to each row.

```
Collapse = function(x) paste(x[x != 0], collapse = "+")
transform(DF, Animals = apply(DF, 1, Collapse))
```

giving:

```
  Animal1 Animal2 Animal3       Animals
1     dog     cat   mouse dog+cat+mouse
2     dog       0   mouse     dog+mouse
3       0     cat       0           cat
```

**2)** Alternately if comma followed by space is ok as the separator then use this for `Collapse`:

```
Collapse <- function(x) toString(x[x != 0])
```

which when used with the `transform` statement in (1) gives:

```
  Animal1 Animal2 Animal3         Animals
1     dog     cat   mouse dog, cat, mouse
2     dog       0   mouse      dog, mouse
3       0     cat       0             cat
```

**3)** Another possibility is to make the `Animals` column a list of vectors:

```
DF2 <- DF
DF2$Animals <- lapply(split(DF, 1:nrow(DF)), function(x) x[x != 0])
```

giving:

```
> DF2
  Animal1 Animal2 Animal3         Animals
1     dog     cat   mouse dog, cat, mouse
2     dog       0   mouse      dog, mouse
3       0     cat       0             cat

> str(DF2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Animal1: chr  "dog" "dog" "0"
 $ Animal2: chr  "cat" "0" "cat"
 $ Animal3: chr  "mouse" "mouse" "0"
 $ Animals:List of 3
  ..$ 1: chr  "dog" "cat" "mouse"
  ..$ 2: chr  "dog" "mouse"
  ..$ 3: chr "cat"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Animal1  Animal2  Animal3
dog      cat      mouse
dog      0        mouse
0        cat      0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  na_if(0) %>%
  mutate(Animals = pmap_chr(., .f = ~stringi::stri_flatten(
    c(...), collapse = " + ", 
    na_empty = TRUE, omit_empty = TRUE)))
```

Which gives:

```
#  Animal1 Animal2 Animal3           Animals
#1    <NA>    <NA>   mouse             mouse
#2     dog     cat   mouse dog + cat + mouse
#3     dog    <NA>   mouse       dog + mouse
#4    <NA>     cat    <NA>               cat
#5    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

---

**Data**

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Animal1 = c("0", "dog", "dog", "0", "0"), 
  Animal2 = c("0", "cat", "0", "cat","0"), 
  Animal3 = c("mouse", "mouse", "mouse", "0","0"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Error in stringi::stri_flatten(c(...), collapse = " + ", na_empty = TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (na_empty = TRUE, omit_empty = TRUE)
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Zach You can't reproduce using `df2` or your own data ?

Comment: No I am okay with the example provided. Unfortunately examples do not do justice to what the real data says all of the time.

Comment: @Zach Could you provide a reproducible example of your actual dataset ?